# Extra navigation bar area shown in swiftUI when view is navigated to by navigation link

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

On view with navigation view

```
NavigationLink(destination: FruitySortedListView(shake: shake), isActive: $showingFruity) { EmptyView() }
```

On view shown in picture:

```
.navigationTitle("Navigation Title")
```

[IMAGE: You can see that there is a lot of extra space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R58lb.png)

Comment: Make sure you haven't got a `NavigationView` in a `NavigationView`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example this works perfectly without the extra space as in the Image.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var isActive = true
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: EmptyView(), isActive: $isActive) {
                VStack {
                    Text("Hi")
                    Spacer()
                }
                .background(Color.red)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Navigation Title")
        }
    }
}

struct EmptyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("navigation")
            Spacer()
        }
        .background(Color.red)
        .navigationTitle("EmptyView")
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```